# Android button behind a frame

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some pieces of android layout code as shown

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/playButton"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="playClick"
    android:background="@drawable/play_icon" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/quitDialog"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

The 'playButton' Button is behind of the 'quitDialog' frame.
When the frame is visible in fullscreen, user can press the button, which is undesirable.
How to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can `button.setClickable(false);` and anytime you want can enable it .

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach to this is to use

```
  playButton.bringToFront();
```

Notice that after bringToFront() you need to call invalidate() on highest level of view to redraw it.

Let me know if this helps or if you need help

Comment: Thanks, but button always behind, it should not be clickable.   button.setClickable(false); is best